# How to get the Email field in a SOQL query mapped from a custom Opportunity field?

Tags: soql, opportunity, account, user

I have custom field in the Opportunity object that is a Lookup and maps the Opportunity object to the User object. I'm trying to write a query that retrieves fields from the Opportunity, and also includes the Email field from the User based on a WHERE clause of AccountId = 'somerandomaccountid'. Apologies if this is confusing, but can anyone help me out with understand cross-object queries with custom fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[SELECT Custom_Field__r.Email, ... FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = '..']
```

assuming the customfield is named Custom_Field__c

If the custom lookup field is named `Foo__c` and points at some object (standard or custom) the relationship name from object to its parent is `Foo__r`

If it is a standard object with a lookup to another standard object and the lookup field is named `FooId`, then the relationship name is `Foo`.

You can lookup the relationship names in any schema browser (such as Workbench) by going to the child object and inspecting the lookup field

Comment: thanks! could you clarify this for me briefly? I am under the impression that fields/columns are separate from relationships

Comment: @user66118 - updated answer; see SOQL guide for more details on relationship fields